# Select option for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**I have sign up form. how can I make select and option form for '<%=' format. can you please help me.**

```
<%= form_for(@patient, url: signup_path, :html => {class: 'register-form', :style => "display: inherit"})  do |f| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">İsim</label>
         <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
             <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control placeholder-no-fix', :placeholder => "İsim" %>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Ülke</label>
         <select name="country" id="select2_sample4" class="select2 form-control">
               <option value="">Ülke Seçiniz...</option>
               <option value="Türkiye">Türkiye</option>
               <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
               <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
               <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
               <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
               <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
               <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn green-haze pull-right">  Kayıt ol  </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague; however, I think I get what you're asking. It looks like your data for the select field is static, so you may try it like this:

Then use the following instead of the HTML you have there:

```
<%= select_tag(:country, options_for_select([['Select Country', '0'], ['Albania', 'Albania']], '0'))%>
```

This will generate the following:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select>
```

If you wanted to have a different default selected, just specify it at the end. For example:

```
<%= select_tag(:country, options_for_select([['Select Country', '0'], ['Albania', 'Albania']], 'Albania'))%>
```

Generates:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
    <option selected = "selected" value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps.